# General Hoeffding inequality with two uncorrelated random vectors

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, inequalities

Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be independent sub-Gaussian variables with sub-Gaussian norm $K$. Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be a random vector such that $\mathbb{E}[a_j X_i]=0$ for all $i,j\in \{1,\ldots ,n\}$ and such that $\left\Vert a \right\Vert_2^2 =1$ almost surely. I'm interested in whether there is a Hoeffding-type bound
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i \geq t] \leq \exp \left(-\frac{ct^2}{K^2} \right) 
\end{align}
as in Theorem 2.6.3 in [this](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) book, just with random $a$. It would be easy if $a$ was independent of $X$. But my question is whether we can have a similar bound when $a$ and $X$ are only uncorrelated.

Comment: Condition on the value of $a$. Then the inequality holds from the fact that $\sum a_i X_i$ is subgaussian, then remove the conditioning

Comment: How do we know that $\sum_i a_i X_i$ is sub-Gaussian conditional on a? It's not obvious to me because $a_i$ and $X_i$ are not fully independent. But I agree that if you can show the sub-Gaussianity with the right sub-Gaussian norm (independent on n), then the inequality follows.

Comment: Consider the case when $a$ is a normalized multiple of $X$ with probability $1/2$ and minus that with probability $1/2$ where the sign flip is independent of $X$. That kills all correlations but is technically the worst case scenario because the sum is as large as it can be half of the time. What are you getting then?

Comment: Thanks, @fedja! Can you please elaborate/ give a reference for why this is the worst case? It would be nice because it would give me a lot of structure for the $a_i$'s I can use to estimate the sub-Gaussian norm.